# Select query on a linking table to get all related results per primary key in one field as comma separated values

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a database with 3 tables: `Employees`, `Clients`, and a linking table. The `Employees` and `Clients` tables have a many-to-many relationship. One or more employee(s) can be working with one or more client(s). Some employees (generally new employees) may not be working with any clients.

The `Employees` table has the following columns:

```
Employoee_ID, Employee_FirstName, Employee_LastName
```

The `Clients` table has these columns:

```
Client_ID, Client_Name, Client_Address
```

I need to write a SQL query on Microsoft SQL Server that selects `Employee_ID`, `Employee_FirstName`, `Employee_LastName`, then has a `Clients` field which lists all of the clients ID's that each employee is working with in one single field.

Tables:

`Employees`:

| Employoee_ID | Employee_FirstName | Employee_LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | Washington |
| 2 | John | Adams |
| 3 | Tom | Jefferson |

`Clients`:

| Client_ID | Client_Name | Client_Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | ClientAl | 1 Al Road |
| 22 | ClientBill | 2 Bill Road |
| 33 | ClientChris | 3 Chris Road |
| 44 | ClientCharlie | 30 Charlie Street |

Linking table

| EmployeeID | ClientID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 33 |
| 3 | 44 |

I need a Microsoft SQL Server query that will return the following output (each employee is listed ONLY once and all of his/ her  related clients' IDs are shown in the same row, in one field, as comma-separated / semicolon-separated values):

| Employoee_ID | Employee_FirstName | Employee_LastName | Clients |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | Washington | 11 |
| 2 | John | Adams | 22;33 |
| 3 | Tom | Jefferson | 44 |

Please advise if you know of a way to do write a query to get the results above. Currently, I am getting each employee multiple times with each client ID in separate rows.

I tried using `SELECT` distinct & other functions but couldn't generate comma separated client ID's in one field for each employee.

Currently my query is listing Employee "John Adams" twice, once with each of its clients.

| Employoee_ID | Employee_FirstName | Employee_LastName | Clients |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | Washington | 11 |
| 2 | John | Adams | 22 |
| 2 | John | Adams | 33 |
| 3 | Tom | Jefferson | 44 |

Tried `select (distinct) EmployeeID` to get each employee only listed once but didn't work in listing all related clientID's in one field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string_agg` - [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
select e.employee_id,
       e.employee_firstname,
       e.employee_lastname,
       string_agg(cli.clientid, ',') AS clients
  from Employees e
left join [linking table] cli
  on e.employee_id= cli.employeeid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2017 you can achieve the desired output via group by and [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function:

```sql
select 
  e.Employoee_ID,
  MAX(e.Employee_FirstName) as Employee_FirstName,
  MAX(e.Employee_LastName) as Employee_LastName,
  STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),ClientID), ';') as Clients
from employoee e
join links l on e.Employoee_ID = l.EmployeeID
join client c on c.Client_ID = l.ClientID
group by e.Employoee_ID
```

Output:

| Employoee_ID | Employee_FirstName | Employee_LastName | Clients |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | Washington | 11 |
| 2 | John | Adams | 22;33 |
| 3 | Tom | Jefferson | 44 |

Check out the [demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c8eb8/7/0).